# Creating an numeric entry with a numeric Keyboard in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-interface, maui

I would like to create a numeric Entry in my .NET MAUI Application. Unfortunately i cant set the keyboard layout to a numeric one. I test my app under iPadOS.

I tried to specify the keyboardtype with the parameter **Numeric**.

```
<Entry Placeholder="Someplaceholder" Text="{Binding Measurment.NumericValue}" Margin="5" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Entry PlaceholderColor="Gray" Placeholder="password" Keyboard="Numeric" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"></Entry>
```

I tried the `Keyboard="Numeric"` in the Entry. it acturally can change the keyboard format. But it is according to the system keyboard format.

[image]

Comment: I have now noticed that too. I think my problem is that the iPad does not have a pure numeric keypad. That's why it can't be displayed on the device. It works perfectly under the other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.
More detail here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/numeric-validation-behavior

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample.Pages.Behaviors.NumericValidationBehaviorPage">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InvalidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ValidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Entry Keyboard="Numeric">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:NumericValidationBehavior 
            InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"
            ValidStyle="{StaticResource ValidEntryStyle}"
            Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
            MinimumValue="1.0"
            MaximumValue="100.0"
            MaximumDecimalPlaces="2" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34479589)